# Post Build event that puts all extra .dlls in bin directory using probing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, probing

I have WPF assembly with a bunch of other dlls in my project

I want to move everything except the main assembly and the app.config from the build directory to a subdirectory called bin

this is easy when I add the probing tag to my app.config and do it manually (a cut and paste job)

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="..." />    
  </connectionStrings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

What i want to do now is automatically move everything that's not the assembly into the bin directory at the end of my build.

so from this

```
App.exe
App.config
Domain.dll
Application.dll
Framework.dll
```

to this

```
App.exe
App.config
bin\Domain.dll
bin\Application.dll
bin\Framework.dll
```

I'm guessing I could use a bat files with a bunch of move commands in it but i was hoping that there was something a bit more reusable and intelligent than that out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone interested what I ended up doing was this

a Post Build Event that looks like this

```
move $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).* .\..
```

and I set the build directory to be the actual sub directory so it looked like

```
[Path to Project]\bin\Release\bin
```

So instead of working out what to move down a directory (which could be a whole bunch of things) I just took the bits I know I want up a directory.

Big smiley face for me Hooray!